# Knowing how/when to deal with Memory Management when using C#, Excel, and Selenium?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I recently have been using C# and Selenium to create loops that import data to a websites' search parameters that will give me results that I paste back into an excel sheet (all within visual Studio).  I have noticed that as I get through more and more searches (as n++;), the speed of the program steadily decreases, even to what looks like a drop in frame rate for my progress bar I have located at the top of the sheet, which leads me to believe the speed of the program is getting slower.  I have also been gathering results after each hour of the program running and it seems that the number of searches my program completes goes down over time.

Is this due to the Garbage Collector not working as I expect it to, due to a lack of knowledge?  Should I be modifying the Memory Management on my end? Is this loop enough to worry about Memory Management?  I know the Garbage Collector is supposed to allocate space for me and I am under the assumption that it also deletes objects no longer in use.  I have little to no experience with Memory Management, so I am just looking for clarification. If this is something I am supposed to handle on my end, can someone point me in the right direction and assist me in learning how to do so?

Here is my script for reference (I go through about 16,000 rows in Excel to complete this specific script).

**EDIT:** Extra Question:  Does it have to do with the fact that I am using a Memory-Heavy call like a Try-Catch?

```
public partial class Sheet1
{
    private void Sheet1_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Sheet1_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #region VSTO Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        this.backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged_1);
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(this.Sheet1_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(this.Sheet1_Shutdown);

    }

    #endregion

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        var CurrentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    }

    //Globals -- for DOBFormatter();
    string day = "";
    string month = "";
    string year = "";
    int n = 0;
    int l = 0;
    string errorfix = "";
    int red = 0;
    int green = 0;
    int r = 6;
    int total = 0;

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            var Excel = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application;
            var activesheet = Excel.ActiveSheet;
            string z = textBox1.Text.ToString();
            n = Convert.ToInt32(z);
            String ActiveCell = Excel.ActiveSheet.Range["A" + n, misValue].Text;
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            if (r == 6)
            {
                while (activesheet.Range["A" + r].Text.ToString().Length > 0)
                {
                    l++;
                    r++;
                    activesheet.Range["E" + 4].Value = "Counting Number of Searches: " + r;
                }
            }
            total = red + green;
            activesheet.Range["E" + 1].Value = "Successful Searches: " + green;
            activesheet.Range["E" + 2].Value = "Failed Searches: " + red;
            activesheet.Range["E" + 3].Value = "Total Searches: " + total;
            activesheet.Range["E" + 4].Value = "Searches Remaining: " + r;
            progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { progressBar1.Maximum = l; });
            //Login to Homepage
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("login-send")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("EMAIL")).SendKeys("####");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("PASSWORD")).SendKeys("####");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("submitButton")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame("homeFrame");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/h3/a[1]")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/div[2]/div[3]/section/ul/li[2]/a/img")).Click();
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[1]);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/input")).Click();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url");
            while (activesheet.Range["A" + n].Text.ToString().Length > 0)
            {
                //Update %, progress bar, and details.                   
                progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 1; });

                //Variables
                string DOS = activesheet.Range["B" + n].Text;
                string PolicyNum = activesheet.Range["C" + n].Text;
                string DOB = activesheet.Range["D" + n].Text;
                string TaxIdOwner = activesheet.Range["A" + n].Text;
                activesheet.Range["A" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Aqua);
                activesheet.Range["B" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Aqua);
                activesheet.Range["C" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Aqua);
                activesheet.Range["D" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Aqua);
                activesheet.Range["E" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Aqua);
                activesheet.Range["F" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Aqua);
                activesheet.Range["G" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Aqua);
                //To get the textboxes in the correct thread that it was created on.
                textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox1.Text = "Currently on row: " + n; });
                textBox2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox2.Text = "Successful searches: " + green; });
                textBox3.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox3.Text = "Failed Searches: " + red; });
                textBox4.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox4.Text = "Total Count: " + total; });
                textBox5.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox5.Text = "Searches Left: " + r; });
                activesheet.Range["E" + 1].Value = textBox2.Text;
                activesheet.Range["E" + 2].Value = textBox3.Text;
                activesheet.Range["E" + 3].Value = textBox4.Text;
                activesheet.Range["E" + 4].Value = textBox5.Text;

                //Select the Correct Search (Policy# + DOB)
                driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[2]/td[1]/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).Click();
                DOBFormatter(DOB);
                //Making a selectors, because it makes the code more simple.
                IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/select"));
                SelectElement selector = new SelectElement(element);
                if (TaxIdOwner == "Company1" || TaxIdOwner == "Company2")
                {
                    selector.SelectByText("Option1");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[9]/td[2]/select")).Click();
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);

                }
                else if (TaxIdOwner == "Company3" || TaxIdOwner == "Company 4")
                {
                    selector.SelectByText("Option2");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).Click();
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);

                }
                else if (TaxIdOwner == "Company5")
                {
                    selector.SelectByText("Option3");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).Click();
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);

                }
                else if (TaxIdOwner == "Company6")
                {
                    selector.SelectByText("Option4");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tbody/tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).Click();
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tbody/tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tbody/tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tbody/tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown);
                    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tbody/tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]/select")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("checkDate")).Clear();
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("checkDate")).SendKeys(DOS);
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("endDate")).Clear();
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("endDate")).SendKeys(DOS);
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("enrolleeNo")).Clear();
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("enrolleeNo")).SendKeys(PolicyNum);
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("dobMM")).Clear();
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("dobMM")).SendKeys(month);
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("dobDD")).Clear();
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("dobDD")).SendKeys(day);
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("dobYYYY")).Clear();
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("dobYYYY")).SendKeys(year);
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("Submit")).Click();
                if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//tr[2]/td[1]/div/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/b/font")).Count > 0)
                {
                    activesheet.Range["E" + n].Value = errorfix;
                    activesheet.Range["A" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["B" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["C" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["D" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["E" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["F" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["G" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    red++;
                }
                else if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/font/b")).Count > 0)
                {
                    errorfix = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/font/b")).Text;
                    activesheet.Range["E" + n].Value = errorfix;
                    activesheet.Range["A" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["B" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["C" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["D" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["E" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["F" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["G" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    red++;
                }
                else if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td/b[font[contains(text(), 'No claims found.')]]")).Count > 0)
                {
                    activesheet.Range["E" + n].Value = "No claims found.";
                    activesheet.Range["A" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["B" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["C" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["D" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["E" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["F" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["G" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    red++;
                }
                else if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//tr[3]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[9]")).Count > 0)
                {
                    if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//tr[3]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[9][contains(text(), 'Denied')]")).Count > 0)
                    {
                        activesheet.Range["F" + n].Value = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[3]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[9][contains(text(), 'Denied')]")).Text;
                        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tbody/tr/td[4]/div/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[12]/a")).Click();
                        activesheet.Range["G" + n].Value = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/span/span")).Text;
                        activesheet.Range["A" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange);
                        activesheet.Range["B" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange);
                        activesheet.Range["C" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange);
                        activesheet.Range["D" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange);
                        activesheet.Range["E" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange);
                        activesheet.Range["F" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange);
                        activesheet.Range["G" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Orange);
                        red++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        activesheet.Range["F" + n].Value = "Approved";
                        activesheet.Range["A" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen);
                        activesheet.Range["B" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen);
                        activesheet.Range["C" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen);
                        activesheet.Range["D" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen);
                        activesheet.Range["E" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen);
                        activesheet.Range["F" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen);
                        activesheet.Range["G" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen);
                        green++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    activesheet.Range["E" + n].Value = "No claims were found";
                    activesheet.Range["A" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["B" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["C" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["D" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["E" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["F" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    activesheet.Range["G" + n].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightPink);
                    red++;
                }
                total++;
                r--;
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url");
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url");
                n++;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            progressBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value - 1; });
            n--;
        }

    }
    private void DOBFormatter(string date)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int position = 0;
        while (count < 3)
        {
            //First go around, grab the first 2 numbers -- the month.
            if (count == 0)
            {
                month = date.Substring(position, 2);
            }
            //Second time, grab the day.
            else if (count == 1)
            {
                day = date.Substring(position, 2);
            }
            //Last go through grabs the year.
            else if (count == 2)
            {
                year = date.Substring(position, 4);
            }
            position = position + 3;
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: _a Memory-Heavy call like a Try-Catch?_ - Huh?

Comment: And when you worry about speed, start by removing those Thread.Sleep() calls.

Comment: @HenkHolterman If I remembered correctly, I had thought Try-Catches were generally a memory intensive call...I could be wrong though.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Additionally, it is not so much the length of the sleeps that are giving me trouble, it seems that as the code runs for a longer amount of time, the searches are taking longer and longer to complete and I am just unsure as to why.

Comment: There are plenty of things that could be proportional to O(n), my guess would be the spreadsheet (that could have more and more work to do in updating ranges etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The try catch is not much of the cause here.  One of the thing that cost a lot on your code would be the number of call to external object (excel and FireFox.)   I would be curious to run a profiler on your code to see where it is getting slower.   It can be as you suspect the Memory of the application not being freed (invoke/COM object can be source of it)  or simply the call towards excel/firefox that are getting heavy to treat for unknown reason.

PS: this is not a true answer but more of a comment.   Hope it can still help you out

Comment: Yes, as someone commented above, I am wrong in saying a Try-Catch is memory intensive, that's just me lacking knowledge, I suppose.  A profile is something that I am not familiar using.  Could you recommend one for me to use?  If not, I am sure a simple google search will help me out with that, just looking if you know of any specific one that could help me scenario.

Comment: I would recommand a google search for the profilling tool that suits you best.   And you might need to extract some of your chunk of code into different method to help the profiller.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you for your help thus far!  Time to learn how to use a profiler :)